# PHP creating XML file empty output

Tags: php, xml

Using PHP I want to read the contents of an xml file as input, do some processing and then output another xml file.

Here is what I have done:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('sms.xml') or die('Failed to create an object');
    $counter = 0;

    foreach($xml as $sms) {
        $this->writer->setIndent(4); 
        $this->writer->startElement('sms');
        $this->writer->writeAttribute('address', $sms->address);
        $this->writer->writeAttribute('time', date("Y-m-d H:i:s", substr($sms->date, 0, 10)));
        $this->writer->writeAttribute('date', $sms->date);
        $this->writer->writeAttribute('type', $sms->type);
        $this->writer->writeAttribute('body', $sms->body);
        $this->writer->writeAttribute('read', 1);
        $this->writer->endElement();         
        $counter++;
    }

    $this->writer->endElement();
    $this->writer->endDocument();

    $filename = "output.xml";
    file_put_contents($filename, $this->writer->flush());
```

When I run the above (via command line) I see the output of the xml (I am not usre why) which looks correct, but the output file simply has a '0' without an xml.

I'm not sure why?

Comment: Manual, have you read it? What does `flush` do? What it returns?

Comment: @u_mulder yes my first port of call was the manual, flush: 'Flush current buffer'. I also tried outputMemory: 'Returns current buffer' - this actually gives me an empty file!

Comment: How is `$this->writer` inited?

Comment: public $writer; $this->writer = new XMLWriter();

Comment: And then you open memory or uri?

Comment: $this->writer->openURI('php://output');

Comment: So then why not `openUri('yourfile')`? And `flush()` will write exactly where you need without `file_put_contents`.